# Product of perfectly-$T_3$ spaces

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

This is (sort of) a continuation of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1857959/product-of-perfectly-t-2-spaces/1858775#1858775)

Let $X$ be a topological space.  Then, we say that $X$ is *perfectly-$T_3$* iff it is $T_1$ and for every $x\in X$ and closed subset $C\subseteq X$ not containing $x$ there is a continuous function $f\colon X\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $\{ x\} =f^{-1}(0)$ and $C=f^{-1}(1)$.

> Is the product of perfectly-$T_3$ spaces necessarily perfectly-$T_3$?

Once again, I think the answer is "No.", but I was initially wrong last time, and that could very well be the case again . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This time your suspicion is correct.

Let $X$ be the [double arrow space](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/10/07/the-lexicographic-order-and-the-double-arrow-space/) (i.e., the subspace of the lexicographically ordered square consisting of the top and bottom edges). As is shown at the link, $X$ is a perfectly normal compact Hausdorff space whose square is not hereditarily normal and hence is not metrizable. The main theorem [here](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/11/18/compact-spaces-with-g-delta-diagonals/) shows that $X$ does not have a $G_\delta$ diagonal. Since the diagonal is closed in $X^2$ but not a $G_\delta$, $X^2$ cannot be perfectly regular.